# How to find the overlap between 2 cell arrays?

Tags: matlab, overlap

I want to find the overlap between this 2 cell arrays by comparing them row by row and get the overlapped rows:

```
ex1={'BRDT','TBP';'php','alm';'BRCA1','TP53'};  
ex2={'TBP','HIST1H2BH';'RB1','TK2';'php','alm'};
desire_output={'php','alm'}
```

I have tried this command and get <2x1 cell>array, but i want <1x2 cell>(whole row)  :

```
 a=intersect(ex1,ex2,'stable');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using *ismember* and picking the required row?

```
ex1={'BRDT','TBP';'php','alm';'BRCA1','TP53'};
ex2={'TBP','HIST1H2BH';'RB1','TK2';'php','alm'};
out = ismember(ex1,ex2) ;
iwant = ex1(all(out,2),:) ;
```

Comment: could you explain to me why this command: iwant = ex1(all(out,2),:); why is ex1 and not ex2 ??

Comment: The result out works for the first input of _ismemebr_. If you want to check with ex2...use ismember(ex2,ex1).

Comment: oh got it ! Thanks